# Inserting urls in bibdesk

Tags: urls, bibdesk

I am working with bibdesk in latex, only when I want to insert URL's in misc. I only get errors. The first image below shows how I am working now:

To [image]

However, I have heard it is possible to add some extra rows, see figure below. But how can I add them? It does not work via tab or enter.

[image]

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibDesk->Preferences->Fields and check the fields you want to add.

Comment: Thanks! That does the job. However, I still get error messages when running my latex code if I insert the url in the url box. How is that possible, do I need to do something else? E.g. placing special brackets or so?

Comment: An example of a not working url is: www.nsf.gov/news/special_reports/survey/index.jsp?id=question and www.nsf.gov/news/special_reports/survey/index.jsp?id=question. Should I make any changes to it?